# Integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{x\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}\coth(sx)\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need help computing this integral:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}\coth(sx)\mathrm{d} x \tag{1}
\end{equation}

I searched through many integral tables and I found this in Gradstein and Ryshik:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}\coth(\pi x)\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{a}{2}e^{-a}-\frac{1}{2}-\cosh(a)\ln(1-e^{-a}) 
\end{equation}

Sadly the book does not have proof of this, so I might try the same method for evaluating $(1)$. Since these two look almost the same there has to be a way to solve $(1)$. If anyone else owns the book and would like to check it out there it's in chapter $4.11-4.12$.

Comment: Maybe it is useful consider $\coth(x):=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}$ and  $\cos(z):=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$ and then consider complex calculus.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804686/show-that-int-0-infty-fracx-cos-ax1x2-coth-frac-pi-x4-dx-frac-p?rq=1

Comment: I considered using complex calculus. But I don't how to tackle a problem like this because of the infinite poles of coth. The link Gary send actually helps a lot since it is very similar to my integral

Comment: I can get $I = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{-a} \cot (s) + \frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{\pi a}{s}}\Phi\left(e^{-\frac{a\pi}{s}},1,1-\frac{s}{\pi}\right)+\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{\pi a}{s}}\Phi\left(e^{-\frac{a\pi}{s}},1,\frac{s}{\pi}+1\right)$ where $\Phi$ is the Lerch transcendent. I can’t write the proof currently, but I will in a few hours. The main idea is to use the series of $\coth (s x)$ that is a consequence of the Mittag-Leffler series expansion of $\cot (z)$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! I'm eagerly waiting for the proof!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x \cos (a x)}{x^2+1} \coth (s x) \, dx$$

Recall the [Mittag-Leffler pole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem) of $\cot (z)$:
$$\cot (z) = \frac{1}{z} + 2z \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^2 - (k \pi)^2}$$
Letting $z \to i s x$ and multiplying by $i$ gives:
$$\coth (s x) = \frac{1}{s x} + 2s x \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(s x)^2 + (k \pi)^2}$$
Substituting this expression in, we have then:
$$I = \frac{1}{s} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (a x)}{x^2+1} \, dx + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2sx^2 \cos (a x)}{(x^2+1)((s x)^2 + (k \pi)^2)} \, dx$$
We can separate the integrals because each converges individually. The first integral has a well-known result:
$$\frac{1}{s} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (a x)}{x^2+1} \, dx = \frac{\pi e^{-a}}{2s}$$

The second integral is a little less trivial, but it can be done.

Mathematica gives:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2sx^2 \cos (a x)}{(x^2+1)((s x)^2 + (k \pi)^2)} \, dx=\frac{\pi^2 k e^{-\frac{\pi a k}{s}}-\pi e^{-a}s}{\pi^2k^2-s^2}$$

Furthermore, Mathematica gives:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi^2 k e^{-\frac{\pi a k}{s}}-\pi e^{-a}s}{\pi^2k^2-s^2} = \frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{\pi a}{s}}\left(\Phi\left(e^{-\frac{a\pi}{s}},1,1-\frac{s}{\pi}\right)+\Phi\left(e^{-\frac{a\pi}{s}},1,1+\frac{s}{\pi}\right)\right)-\frac{\pi e^{-a}}{2s}+\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-a}\cot(s)$$
Where $\Phi$ is the [Lerch transcendent.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function)

Thus summing the two results, we have:

$$I = \frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{\pi a}{s}}\left(\Phi\left(e^{-\frac{a\pi}{s}},1,1-\frac{s}{\pi}\right)+\Phi\left(e^{-\frac{a\pi}{s}},1,1+\frac{s}{\pi}\right)\right)+\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-a}\cot(s)$$

However, this expression does not hold for $s$ being an integer multiple of $\pi$ due to $\cot (s)$ causing it to be an indeterminate when one takes the limit, so there needs to be some finesse for evaluating these cases. I'm not sure if there is simplification possible for the result I obtained for $I$ involving $\Phi$.

Comment: If this is correct then the limit $s \rightarrow \pi$ should agree with the second integral in my original post.

Comment: It agrees everywhere but integers multiples of $\pi$ strangely. Taking the limit just gives indeterminate since the limits from above and below don’t agree and just explode to infinity.

Comment: I checked the expression you wrote for $s=\pi/4$ and $s=\pi/2$ and it agrees with the result in Gradstein and Ryshik which means it truly is correct. I will try to take the limit for $s\rightarrow \pi$ but I'm not sure if I know how to calculate it since I'm not familiar at all with the Lerch transcendent. Anyways, I think you can consider the integral specifically for $s=\pi$, make use of the integration table and then say that for $s \neq \pi$ your solution holds, therefore considering it solved.